# Am I allowed to have an irrational distance for a rational metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

First off, this "might" sound like a duplicate question, but I couldn't really find a relevant question so I am posting this thread.

Consider rational metric space $Q$, and suppose $p \in Q$. (Here, I am assuming that the existence of Real Field $R$ is unknown yet)

Then, am I allowed to use an irrational distance to define a neighborhood of p? (e.g. $N_{\sqrt2}(p)$) Of course, I can do something like: $\{q \in Q: (d(p,q))^2<2\}$. Here's my dilemma. If I were to use the first expression, everything can be described in a neat form, but $\sqrt2$ is not defined in $Q$. On the other hand, if I were to use the second expression, it just overcomplicates things that can be neatly described by the former expression. Or, is there an alternate way to describe this set? Any help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: A metric is defined as a function $d\colon X\times X\to \Bbb{R}$, you first you must define what a "metric" is if you don't know what $\Bbb{R}$ is

Comment: The values taken by a metric on a set $S$ do not have to be restricted by any numbers that happen to belong to $ S.$  If  $ d$ is a metric on $ S$ then for any real $r>0,$ the metric $e(x,y)=r\cdot d(x,y)$ yields the same set of open balls.

Comment: got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking whether balls of irrational radius are open in the topology generated by balls of rational radius, then the answer is yes.

Suppose $s>0$ is irrational. Let $(r_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be an increasing sequence of positive rationals such that $r_i \to s$. Then for any point $x$ we have that $$\bigcup_i B(x; r_i) = B(x; s) $$ which is open as a union of open balls.